# Where to find fuel type & fuel consumption info for PW 1000G engines family?

Tags: jet-engine, fuel, datasets

Where I can find the information about fuel type and fuel consumption for PW 1000G engines family?

Comment: It's a commercial jet engine, so it runs Jet-A. Fuel consumption depends on power setting, airspeed, temperature, and pressure. It would probably be more effective to ask about typical fuel consumption for a specific aircraft equipped with PW 1000G family engines.

Comment: It may be hard to find fuel consumption, especially since no planes with these engines are in service yet.

Comment: To raptortech97  - Jet A, or may be Jet A-1?

Comment: [This database](https://easa.europa.eu/document-library/icao-aircraft-engine-emissions-databank) has fuel flow information as well as emissions data, but I did not see the PW1000 series (or LEAP) in there yet. It will be operated around the world, so it will be able to use Jet A or A-1.

Comment: To **fooot** - _Site under maintenance_ when try to download.

Comment: It's working now!

Answer (score 2):

In [this presentation](http://www.lawa.org/uploadedFiles/lax/noise/presentation/noiseRT_090513_Pratt%20and%20Whitney%20Presentation.pdf) from 2009 PW quote savings of 140 gallons on a 500 nm trip. I presume they are comparing it to current engine options such as the IAE V2500.

Comment: I see only "savings", not absolute consumption value.

Comment: @Y.N I have noticed that engine makers tend not post absolute values until they enter operation. Possibly because it is partly dependent on the type of aircraft it's fitted on.